# How to Filter serilog with UseSerilogRequestLogging

Tags: serilog, serilog-expressions

I'm using serilog and try to filter out HTTP Methods that are not POST, GET, PUT,  and DELETE. for example filter out OPTIONS Method.

I also use UseSerilogRequestLogging and Serilog.Expressions.

Everything work fine, Serilog is great.
But the filter does't work. Any idea why?

Here is my code:

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory 
    loggerFactory)
{
    ...
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(opt => opt.EnrichDiagnosticContext = 
    LogHelper.EnrichFromRequest);
    ...
}
```

LogHelper.cs:

```
public static class LogHelper
    {
        public static async void EnrichFromRequest(IDiagnosticContext diagnosticContext, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var request = httpContext.Request;
            diagnosticContext.Set("Protocol", request.Protocol);
        }
    }
```

and appsettings.json:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Expressions" ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByExcluding",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "@Properties['Protocol'] like '%OPTIONS%'"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark, but have you tried either of these formats instead?

```
"Args": {
      "expression": "Protocol like '%OPTIONS%'"
}

"Args": {
      "expression": "Contains(Protocol, 'OPTIONS') ci"
}
```